# Haskell basic "check" function

Tags: regex, haskell

I have this homework problem and I am absolutely lost... So the problem says "Fill in the definitions of the Sing and (:.:) cases for the "check" function." I am confused what the Regex and Maybe String mean. Also not quite sure what a lot of the syntax is and every time I look up videos I never understand it. I have been programming with c++ and c for a while and understand it well so examples in those would be good if that is possible. Instructions on how to test the function would be great. I know how to compile it and run it in GHCI but I don't know what to type in to trigger the test for that function.

The code looks like this

```
check :: Regex -> String -> Maybe String
check Epsilon cs = Just cs
check (Sing c) (c':cs) = c' + cs
check (r1 :.: r2) cs = r1 + r2
check (r1 :|: r2) cs =
    case check r1 cs of
        Just cs' -> Just cs'
        Nothing  -> check r2 cs
check (Plus r) cs =
    case check r cs of
        Just cs' -> case check (Plus r) cs' of
            Just cs'' -> Just cs''
            Nothing   -> Just cs'
        Nothing -> Nothing
check _ _ = Nothing
```

So the `c' +cs` on line 3 is my attemped and the isntructions say that the next line will be very similar but I tried `r1 + r2` this out and it doesn't even compile.

```
data Regex
  = Epsilon           -- empty string
  | Sing Char         -- single character
  | (:.:) Regex Regex -- concatenation
  | (:|:) Regex Regex -- alternation
  | Plus Regex        -- repetition (one or more)
```

Comment: Please include the code as text, not an image. That said, you are expected to [show your own effort on homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) so we know what specific issue you are having. We won’t do your homework for you but we can help you understand how to do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I wasn't able to format the code correctly for some reason. But yeah I just want some explanations if possible. I completely understand that my homework would be done for me.

Comment: You can format a b;ock of code by selecting it and hitting the `{}` button.

Comment: My goodness... Got it. Thanks a lot for that! @Davislor

Comment: Oh, and a good way to test the function on a given input is `ghci -e`, for example: `ghci -e "check (Sing 'a') "abb" check.hs`.  You can also add your test cases to the file itself, such as `testcase1 = check (Sing 'a') "abb"`, and you can write a simple test driver for it, as in `main = foldMap print [check (Sing 'a') "abb", check (Sing 'a' :|: Sing 'b') "abb"]` and so on for your other test cases.  This takes a list of test cases, maps it to a list of `IO` actions that print out each test case, then combines that list to a single `IO` action that prints them all, which runs as `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, since this is homework (and also not a MCVE), but the general approach I would suggest for this kind of problem is to replace the parts you haven't written yet with what's called a *typed hole*.  That is, change the lines with `error` statements to the following:

```
check (Sing c) (c':cs) = _
check (r1 --- r2) cs = _
```

GHC will then give you a compile error that tells you what the type of the hole is and which variables are in scope with the right types to fill it.  You can suppress this error to compile and test the rest of the code, and only crash the program if the hole is actually executed, like `error` does, with the `-fdefer-typed-holes` command-line option.

If you're partly sure of the solution, you can partly fill in the hole. Let's say your hole is a function from a list of one type to a list of another type.  You might then try `map _`.  If you're taking in a list `(c':cs)` and returning a list, it might possibly have the form `(_ c'):(check _ cs)`.  If you need to return a `Maybe` something, you could try `Just _`.  Keep filling in the holes with functions of the right types until you have a working program.

`Regex` is some kind of type (presumably representing a *regular expression*), which should have been defined in a libraary you were given, along with the functions you have available to work with them.  The `check` function is supposed to take two arguments, a `Regex` and a `String`.  (Presumably, it's checking whether the `String` matches the `Regex`?)  A `Maybe String` is a type that contains either `Just` a `String` or `Nothing`, so in this context, I'm guessing you're supposed to return either a portion of the string that matches, or `Nothing` if there is no match.  But the assignment should give you a specification.

Comment: Okay that helped a lot! I will go through and try your solutions. I feel like I almost have it. and yes you are correct, the regex is defined. I will edit the code to show what the regex was defined as

Answer (score 1):

> Instructions on how to test the function would be great.

You did not state the purpose of the function, so I'll make an educated guess.

The function `check re str` takes a regexp `re` and a string `str`, and checks whether a *prefix* of `str` matches with `re`. On success `Just str2` is returned, where `str2` is the *rest* of `str` after the matching prefix. Of failure, `Nothing` is returned.

(BTW, I don't think this interface allows for implementing the correct backtracking on the alternative case, but I'll neglect that.)

Some test cases:

`check (Sing 'a' :.: Sing 'b') "abc"` matches string "abc" with the regexp "ab": the result should be `Just "c"`.

`check (Sing 'a' :.: Sing 'b') "axbc"` should be `Nothing`.

`check (Plus (Sing 'a') :.: Sing 'b') "aaaaaabc"` should be `Just "c"`.

`check ((Sing 'a' :|: Sing 'A') :.: Sing 'b') "abc"` should be `Just "c"`.

`check ((Sing 'a' :|: Sing 'A') :.: Sing 'b') "Abc"` should also be `Just "c"`.